# Angular translate useSanitizeValueStrategy does not work at all

Tags: angular-translate, ngsanitize

I have a problem with angular translates useSanitizeValueStrategy.
It does nothing regardless what configuration i use. 
I am using the async loader to load my translations.
It is an ASP.net MVC web api project.

Things I did to make it work :

- implemented ngSanitize
- tried multiple configurations

```js
  $translateProvider.useUrlLoader('api', {
                queryParameter: 'langId'
            })
                .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'de'])
                .preferredLanguage('en')
                .fallbackLanguage('de')
        .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape'); // tried every configuration I found
```

I also tried to seperate the useSanitizeValueStrategy like     `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');`

or tried to change the position of the command but this did not work either.

any suggestions why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
```

Try above-given line into your application configuration where you configuring your angular-translate library. In above given an answer with Strategy `escape.` This will escape HTML in the translation. You can also find many [options](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security) here.